# Telerik mvc combobox: Prevent write value different from the list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, combobox, telerik

I have a telerik combobox in mvc3 application and I want to prevent the user writing a value different from the list being loaded from the controller.

A thing that partial helped is to set the textbox input to be readonly but then:
1. The user can filter the list by the textbox.
2. The user can erase his selection.

Another thing that I thought about is: What the user types in the select is the value not the description, so I need it to prevent writing text different from the description while the value remains encapsulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you still looking to have the user be able to input custom text? If not you can use the DropDownList functionality as seen on [this demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox).

If you still want the user to be able to type into the component but somehow have it aware of when they either misspell something, or type one character more than necessary, this can be extremely difficult. You would essentially have to have some clever JavaScript to be triggered with every key press and check the current value against a list. With users being pretty quick with typing, or their browsers being old, this can be very unreliable. Plus, a user can easily disable JavaScript at any time making this functionality obsolete.

I think your best options is to have it as is, where the user can type whatever they want. You can always have validation on the item they have typed and upon blur() or a POST (whatever fits your application) have a message appear to warn them of an invalid entry.